# OpenRefine - splits multiple values in columns and fill with 1 or respective name

Tags: openrefine

My csv is a survey.
My customers could fill 1 or more flavours of ice cream.
For example: Alice answered Chocolate , Caramel.

**Costumer**   |  **Flavour**

Alice       |  Chocolate , Caramel

Chris    |  Cream, Chocolate

Daniel | Cream, Watermelon

[Printscreen of table above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lZRh.png)

How can I transform the flavours in columns and fill with 1 or the name of flavour in respective cell.

There are more than 60 flavours of ice cream.

**Costumer** | **Chocolate** | **Caramel** | **watermelon**

Alice  | 1 | 1  | 0 |

Chris |  1 |  0 | 1 |

Daniel |  0 |  1 |  1

[Printscreen of table above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKg44.png)

Comment: maybe show us the code you have used to try this already?
Please check the how toask a question in the knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough problem that happens all too often. Here's how I would approach this problem.

First, split cell values to separate the Flavour column to have one value per row. See this [tutorial](https://guides.library.illinois.edu/openrefine/splitting#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20column%20you,%2C%20and%20select%20%E2%80%9COK.%E2%80%9D) from the University of Illinois, they've got lots of great OpenRefine tutorials. Then you should have a table like:

```
Name   | Flavour
------ | ----------
Alice  | Chocolate
       | Caramel
Chris  | Cream
       | Chocolate
Daniel | Cream
       | Watermelon
```

Second, fill down the Name column. You may need to switch to Record mode. See [OpenRefine docs](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Cell-Editing#fill-down-and-blank-down) for more on Fill down.

```
Name   | Flavour
------ | ----------
Alice  | Chocolate
Alice  | Caramel
Chris  | Cream
Chris  | Chocolate
Daniel | Cream
Daniel | Watermelon
```

I don't think OpenRefine's transpose feature will *spread* levels in the Flavour like you want them to, without getting into a lot of GREL black magic. I'd would then try to import it into Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel. Then add a new column that is just filled with "1".

```
Name   | Flavour    | Value 
------ | ---------- | ----- 
Alice  | Chocolate  | 1
Alice  | Caramel    | 1
Chris  | Cream      | 1
Chris  | Chocolate  | 1
Daniel | Cream      | 1
Daniel | Watermelon | 1
```

With this structure, you should be able to construct a pivot table to get your data into that final format. Make sure that you're not using an aggregation function when you specify value.

Add comments if you run into trouble.